# Extract image URI from markdown files using sed/grep containing duplicates in a single line

Tags: bash, sed, grep, markdown, lynx

I have some markdown files to process which contain links to images that I wish to download. e.g. a markdown file:

```markdown
[![](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png)](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png)

a lot of text 
some more text...

[![](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/take_a_break_git.gif)](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/take_a_break_git.gif)


some more text

another URL but not image
[https://github.com]

so on
```

I am trying to parse through this file and extract the list of image URLs, which I can later pass on `wget` command to download.

So far I have used `grep` and `sed` and have got results:

```sh
$ sed -nE "/https?:\/\/[^ ]+.(jpg|png|gif)/p" $path
[![](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png)](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png)
[![](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/take_a_break_git.gif)](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/take_a_break_git.gif)

$ grep -Eo "https?://[^ ]+.(jpg|png|gif)" $path
https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png)](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/take_a_break_git.gif)](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ze2SiBflkZ4/XbtF1TjELcI/AAAAAAAALL4/IDC6W-b5moU0eGu2eN60aZ4pxfXW1ybmQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/take_a_break_git.gif
```

The regex is essentially working fine, but the issue is that as the **same URL is present twice in the same line**, the text selected is the first occurrence of `https` and last occurrence of `jpg|png|gif`. But I want the first occurrence of `https` and first occurrence of `jpg|png|gif`

How can fix this?

P.S. I have also tried `lynx -dump -image_links -listonly $path` but this prints the entire file.

I am also open to other options that solve the purpose, and as long as I can hook the code up in my current shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add square brackets into the negated bracket expression:

```sh
grep -Eo "https?://[^][ ]+\.(jpg|png|gif)"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/E0DW2j). *Details*:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `[^][ ]+` - one or more chars other than `]`, `[` and space
- `\.` - a dot
- `(jpg|png|gif)` - either of the three alternative substrings.

Comment: That was clever! thanks! one more doubt, why did you add a `\\` before the dot?

Comment: @Amita `.` matches any chars. `\.` matches a dot only.